# How to to make a gap between rows in FlowPanel in Css in Gwt?

Tags: html, css, gwt, gwtp

Look at this image[image]

The picture is showing a FlowPanel that is holding many Labels. If there are more labels then the labels will flow into next row.

However, as you see, there is no gap between rows in this flowpanel.

```
    .flowPanel{
         spacing:3px;
    }
```

The above css didn't work.

So, how to make the gap between rows in this flowpanel to 3px in CSS in GWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `margin-bottom` for these elements. They should be `display:inline-block` (or `display:inline-block` with `float:left`) for this to work.

Comment: u means do this for the Label?

Comment: Yes for all labels (`phone-in`, `phone`, `pay-phone`...).

Comment: thax you very much, it's perfect